# Static Front Page settings - distinguish between Front page and Post page

Tags: customization

Let's say we go for `Admin` - `Appreance` - `Customize` - **`Static Front Page`**

There we can see the `Front page` and `Post page` options when we select **`A static page`**

These two options are not there if we pick up **`Your latest posts`**

So my question is, what is the difference between `Front page` and `Post page`? A [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress%20Static%20Front%20Page%20settings%20-%20distinguish%20between%20Front%20page%20and%20Post%20page) didn't help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both are pages. For front page create a page with content. For posts page create an empty page ( no content ). Now select them in customizer accordingly.

Comment: Where can we view such a `Posts page` @Frank?

Comment: Add this page to the menu and call it from there. In admin area go to Pages -> All Pages and view your Posts page there.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. From `Front Page`, how can we browse to `Posts Page`?

Comment: Add Posts page to the menu. Make menu visible on Front page. Selected Posts page from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Front Page**

The page you set to Front Page will be displayed when you visit your website at first (Something like Homepage of your site). If you don't use this setting, your site will display the list of blog posts in stead whenever someone visits the site when the site launches.

**Posts page**

The page you set to Posts page will display the list of blog posts (normally called Blog page) in stead of its contents whenever someone visits this page of your site.

Comment: Thanks @TrangDinhVan. From `Front Page`, how can we browse to `Posts Page`?

Comment: Use menu bar, we can browse to any pages.
Go to Dashboard > Appearance > Menu and set the menu bar there (it is up to the support of the current used theme)